# Optimally Connecting 2 routers to avoid double NAT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, adsl-router, routing-table

My d-link DSL router router is a wired only router. It has just 1outport -  Ethernet port & this connects to the WAN port of a Linksys WRT 110 802.1N WiFi router .  If I keep the DSL router in "router" mode & let it authenticate my ADSL ISP A/C , I run into a double. NAT situation because both routers will do NAT. If I disable NAT in either - I am offline.
If I let the DSL router authenticate ISP 
, I keep getting frequent dropouts of connectivity.
So what I have done right now is keep the DSL router in Bridge mode. The actual authentication for a PPOE connection is done by wireless Linksys router. This way I am not facing a double NAT situation.
Initially this arrangement work nicely but now I do keep on getting dropouts every now and often and have to reboot my routers.
So here are my questions
--- is it possible to run any kind of R I P
Between both these routers 
-- what are other options after configuring these two routers so that they work with each other and only one of them does NAT.
How about a DMZ ?
So far  the  options  I have in  mind to configure these together , are

- Bridge mode for DSL
- RIP between two routers. But I don't know much about this.  someone will have to tell me how to do it.
- DMZ on the DSL. Router.
  Is there anything else that is doable and I have missed it... let me know please.

You may ask why I am doing this as against just one WiFi aDSL router..... that won't give me the range this one gives

Comment: You don’t need RIP. A static route will suffice. However, bridge mode is better. You could also use the second router purely as an Access Point. That being said, if I understand correctly, you get connection problems in any configuration. It could simply be that your ADSL connection itself is not stable.

Comment: You should be bridging, are you sure its not just a DSL modem?

Comment: Router 1 is an ADSL modem & router 2 is a plain  Ethernet router that takes an  Ethernet  cable in it's WAN  port.

Comment: There is an option when you put the ADSL router in bridging mode to encapsulate packets using VCMUX  or LLC . Those later abbreviations maybe slightly off.... just re collecting em off the bat ( I can't get the DSL router via WiFi over  web. Have to physically connect it with cable to get to it )

Comment: Would changing data option  mentioned above have any impact